# Need browser client socket to get data from server socket

Tags: javascript, vb.net, sockets, razor

I have a server set up to get a client request via socket and return a string. The socket server is in VB, tested and it works with another VB client. But I need to have the client run for javascript
on an CSHTML page. So when I click a button it fires a js function to make a socket call to retrieve some text.
I'm not familiar with javescript and am not sure what I need to make it run. What library,package
nuget do I need to make it run?
Javascript is as user friendly as the is no IntelliSense or breakpoints to help.

This is my code , first part is the simple VB code that only needs Imports System.Net.Sockets
the second part is my feeble attempt at client code. I put to the SAPinfo textarea just so I'd know the code passed through there! I tried a few examples for sockets but no result. I seem to be missing a reference of some sort. I read some articles that mention browser sockets are not supported but that socket.io under javascript might !

```
Dim listenerSocket As Socket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    Dim ipend As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 4305)
    listenerSocket.Bind(ipend)
    listenerSocket.Listen(0)
    Dim clientSocket As Socket = listenerSocket.Accept()
    Dim Buffer As Byte() = New Byte(clientSocket.SendBufferSize - 1) {}
 readByte = clientSocket.Receive(Buffer)
        Dim rData As Byte() = New Byte(readByte - 1) {}
        Array.Copy(Buffer, rData, readByte)

 ************  client code is next    **********************
function Getsap() {
    var textBox = "Hello world!";
     $('#SAPinfo').val(textBox);

    var io = require('socket.io-client');
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4305', { reconnect: true });

    // Add a connect listener
    socket.on('connect', function (socket) {
        console.log('Connected!');
    });
    socket.emit('CH01', 'me', 'test msg');
}
```

Thanks

I'm using Visual studio 2019.

Comment: Ok, but maybe I need to do some learning here but isn't one of the main benefits of razor you don't have to use javascript?

Comment: This is an existing cshtml page that used javascript to modify other fields. I thought adding a socket connection would be fairly easy thing and since javescript was used already , I tried to use it as well.  This is a MVC application so I didn't want to go back to the controller to make the socket call. Seemed simpler this way.

Comment: I should mention that the VB socket server is local and interfaces with a SAPGUI client.